# Mac: DRM removal for Apple TV-purchased movies?

Tags: macos, catalina, drm

I have the latest macOS (Catalina). Are there any DRM removal software that will work with the Apple TV app on my Mac? The most popular software (DVDFab, TunesKit, etc.) work with iTunes only, but iTunes only exists on iPhones. I downloaded my Apple TV-purchased movie to my Mac, which has a .movpkg file extension. I tried using TunesKit, but it won't even open the downloaded movie. I'm just looking to convert the file extension and play in VLC so I can take a screenshot from a movie scene.

I understand that Apple blanks DRM from screen recording and I still want to snap occasional still frames.

Is this technically possible?

Comment: My setup is VMWare + a Windows VM + Windows iTunes + Windows Tuneskit. Works wonderfully, and I'm not at the whim of Apple OS changes. But, all of this method is much too much effort for just a screenshot.

Comment: I would love an answer @Wowfunhappy so I can learn how windows tunes kit works…

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be hard to accomplish using Apple SDK and tools. I’ll be setting aside any reason why Apple made it technically hard, as *why Apple does things is off topic here*.

What is not technically hard is using HDMI capture hardware to make your grabs. Or better, find a like-minded community that is sharing the burden and cost of getting high quality still frames for educational and legitimate and legal uses. (Also, [what is legal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Term_Extension_Act) is often something that’s not moral (which also is relative in many cases) or even [good for some segment of society](https://film-grab.com/category/1998/).)

Crowd sourcing has many benefits here in getting around technical hurdles.

- https://film-grab.com/category/1976/
- https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/hdmi-capture-devices